# Opinion Polls (Cambridge Stats Notes) - Clarification Required

Tags: statistics

Looking at [these](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/stats/Sa4.pdf) again.

Page 18 describes opinion polls. I understand everything up to where they say this:

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \hat{p} - 0.03 \leq p \leq \hat{p} + 0.03 \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( -\frac{0.03}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}} \leq \frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}} \leq \frac{0.03}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}}  \right)$$

I don't understand how they jump from the lhs to the rhs. Any tips, please?

Also how do they then go to the next line? (the approximate one). Thank you.

EDIT:

I was about to write that I get the following, to obtain $p$ in the middle:

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \hat{p} - \eta \sqrt{p(p-1)/n} \leq p \leq \hat{p} - \xi \sqrt{p(1-p)n} \right)$$

is this actually useful, hmm

Comment: Subtract $\hat{p}$ from both sides and divide by $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh. I see thanks...

Comment: very neat. I like it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: um the numerator is then $p-\hat{p}$

Comment: ahh, that's actually correct, because then the mean is zero

Comment: one more q, why aren't phis in the notes like that and not like: $\Phi \left( 0.03/ \sqrt{p(1-p)/n} \right)$, i.e. where did the division go to

Comment: because if we draw parallell to a standard normal distrib, then if $X \sim N(0,1)$, we would expect that $\mathbb{P} (-1.96 < X < 1.96) = \Phi (1.96) - \Phi (-1.96)$

Comment: gee... that's literally the same.